# How to select only value greater than... in columns data grid

Tags: reactjs

is there a way how to define that only "data" greater than * should be added to my columns in data grid?

I have tried add filter, but it support only exact value.

In my example i want to add only columns which has "combinationId" greater than 100.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getCleanState();
          this.reload();
    }

    getCleanState() {
        return {

            columns:[
                { name: 'combinationId', title: 'ID kombinace'},
                { name: 'name', title: 'Název kombinace'},
            ],
            defaultColumnWidths: [
                { columnName: 'combinationId', width: 160 },
                { columnName: 'name', width: 200 },

              ],
            rows:[] 

        };
    }

    reload() {          

        axios.get('http://private-anon-27979f8bb8-bulgur.apiary-mock.com/api/v1/combinationInfo').then((response) => {
            this.loading = false;           
            var newState = {columns: this.state.columns, rows: response.data
                .map(x => x.combinations)
                .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))};
            this.setState(newState);
        }, (error) => {
            this.loading = false;
        })  
    }


    render() {    
        const { columns, rows, defaultColumnWidths, integratedFilteringColumnExtensions } = this.state;
        return ( 
            <div>
        {/* <button onClick={() => this.reload()}>Load</button>*/}
        <div className="grids">
                <div className="patient-container">

                <Grid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}>
                    <Table />
                    <TableColumnResizing defaultColumnWidths={defaultColumnWidths} />
                    <TableHeaderRow />
                </Grid>
                  </div>
                  <div className="patient-container2">
                  <Grid 
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}>
                    <FilteringState defaultFilters={[{ columnName: 'combinationId', value: 100 }]} /> <IntegratedFiltering />

                    <Table />
                    <TableColumnResizing defaultColumnWidths={defaultColumnWidths} />
                    <TableHeaderRow />
                </Grid>
                </div>
                   </div>
            </div>)
    }   
}
```

Thanks for answers. I wish you great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does it have to be dynamic filtering? else you could just filter it before returning

```
 render() {    
        const { columns, rows, ... } = this.state;
        const filteredRows = rows.map(row => row.combinationId >= 100);
        return ( ...
```

Comment: I finally solved it differently. in render method added filter <Grid
     rows={rows.filter(function(name){return name.combinationId <= 106 && !(name.combinationId === 100)})}